# git clone give an empty repository but the repository isn't empty

Tags: git, gitlab

Strange behavior of git.
We tried to git clone a repository which is on gitlab. The repository is not empty: some directories and some scripts. We can download it using the gitlab webUI.
But we get an empty repository using git clone cmd:

```
Cloning into 'aft'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

The behavior is the same from other computers. We tried to reboot gitlab it is the same.

If we git clone other repository it works perfectly there is just this one particular repository with this strange behavior. It works well until recently, the most notable change is a commit from a new user who works on a Windows platform.

EDIT: Thanks to VonC I tried it using http instead ssh and it worked. I have the correct repository with all my files and the correct configuration for remotes. I followed this: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1930 but git is in the gitlab group as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not much here to work with. Are your remotes set up correctly?

Comment: git clone work perfectly on other repository, but for this one specificly it get an empty repository, but this is not an empty repository.

Comment: Do you have erroneously broad `gitignore` rules in place? Does the repo have commits, or just files?

Comment: Is there a default branch set that is empty?

Comment: No .gitignore. There are several commits. In fact it worked perfectly well untill recently. We had a commit from a new user (he works on Windows environment if it's useful). The default branch on the remote is master with all commits and files. The empty repository with git clone have nothing.

Comment: Is it similar to https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3151? Or an ownership issue as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1930?

Comment: it's more this one: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1930. It worked using http instead of ssh. git is in gitlab group as expected. So it seems linked to ssh but again I can clone other repository perfectly well but not this particular one.

Answer (score 0):

On your server repository, on `info/refs`, your last commit is described?
If not, execute

```
git update-server-info
chown apache info/refs
```